# How to create a transparent activity? which will start after every 5 minutes.And the background should remain what it was

Tags: android

I am creating an application which will call a new transparent activity to launch every 5 minutes.whether the phone is locked or not.

Every thing is working fine.But the problem is when this activity is started,it will start on
a MAIN Launcher activity.

I want to show that activity on Desktop, menu or whatever user is in.

How can i do this?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.spec.test"
              android:versionCode="1"
              android:versionName="1.0">
            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

            <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

                <activity android:name=".BroadCastDemoActivity"
                          android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
            <activity android:name=".TransparentActivity"
                android:label="Transparent"
                android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
                </activity>        
        <receiver android:name="MyBroadCastReceiver"></receiver>
        <service android:name="MyService"></service>
            </application>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>
            <uses-permission android:name="DEVICE_POWER"></uses-permission>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

        </manifest>
```

Comment: how do you want to show a transparent activity ?

Comment: Suppose user is at home, then the activity will be shown on home screen with transparent effect. In my case, when i am at home and activity is started then the activity is shown on the launcher activity of my application.So launcher activity will also be shown.

Comment: why the transparent activity  isn't your launcher ?? 

can you post your manifest file?

Comment: This is my Manifeast.xml file.The launcher activity is different.I want to show an activity that enables user to add some value at every 5 minutes.So i need to show a different activity which is not a launcher activity.

Answer (score 0):

You `TransparentActivity` needs an `<intent-filter>` change your TransparentActivity part in the manifest to this

```
        <activity android:name=".TransparentActivity"
            android:label="Transparent"
            android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Or to this if you want the transparent activity to start when you start the application from the users homescreen.

```
        <activity android:name=".TransparentActivity"
            android:label="Transparent"
            android:theme="@style/YourTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: if you used the `...Main` and the `...LAUCNHER` than you should change the `BroadCastDemoActivity` intent-filer to `...VIEW` and `...DEFAULT`. When you have 2 launcher activities Android doesn't know which one to start

Comment: I got my answer.It was so simple i just need to add android:launchMode="singleInstance" attribute in androidManifeast file in my MAIN activity.Thanx for your support.